# Regular Expression Matching in SAS

Tags: regex, perl, sas

I have observations that have 1 dollar signs ($), and observations that have 2 dollar signs ($).  I want to assign different values to each type of observation.  It should look something like this:

"$200 $300" gets assigned 1.
"$200" gets assigned 2.

I've tried playing with Perl wildcards all day but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the SAS `countc()` function to count the number of times '$' appears?

```
%put %sysfunc(countc($300 $400,'$'));  /* returns 2 */
%put %sysfunc(countc($300 ,'$'));      /* returns 1 */
```

Comment: Crap.  Forgot that SAS had all these fun super-specific functions.  Yeah, that makes total sense.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [goatse operator](http://socialtext.net/perl5/goatse_operator):

```
my @str = ( '$200 $300', '$200' );

foreach my $str ( @str ) {
    my $count =()= $str =~ /\$/g;
    print "count for $str is $count\n";
}
```

Then depending on what your `$count` is, assign the values accordingly.